# Selenium Won't scroll down after opening when pulling urls from csv file

Tags: python, selenium

So, i'm pulling urls from a csv that i need to scroll down until it can't scroll anymore.  It will go through the urls 1 after another.  Without taking the time to stop and scroll down.  I'm tried time.sleep() but it doesn't work.

However, If i work with 1 url (not pulling it from file), it works like a champ.

Here are a few url's for reference.

I appreciate any suggestions you all might have.

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=Los%20Angeles%20remodeling
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=Boston%20remodeling
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=Chicago%20remodeling



import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



driver = webdriver.Firefox()

_browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
_browser_profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=_browser_profile)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
username.send_keys("email****")
password.send_keys("password****")
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
time.sleep(2)

with open('fb_urls.csv') as f_input, open('fb_profile_urls.csv', 'w', newline='')  as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    for url in csv_input:
        driver.get(url[0])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        match=False
        while(match==False):
            lastCount = lenOfPage
            time.sleep(1)
            lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
            if lastCount==lenOfPage:
                match=True
        soup = bs(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_32mo'), "lxml")
        csv_output.writerow(soup)
```

Here is the code to have the google driver ignore the Notification PopUps

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: By sleep, do you mean `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`? This does not do anything on it's own. You need to specify [until when](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) should it wait. That 10 species only that it will timeout after 10 seconds (but meaningless without an `until` clause specified). As an ugly solution you could try a real sleep (it's never recommended, but I find it acceptable in scripts that you will never use again).

Comment: i tried time.sleep() and it's not working.  I mean, it does pause it, but it still won't recognize the scroll down part of the code.  it's just running through the urls rapid fire like.  I even tried putting a loop inside of the for url loop to run the scroll down code.  I'm new to this, about 2 months in, but logic tells me that should work.  Alas, it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was something to do with the Firefox Webdriver.  Switched over to Chrome and it works.  In addition to the code above, i've provided the proper code needed to have Google ignore the Notification PopUp.